# How to send single value along with Formdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a file control which is as below :

```
<input id="fileUpload" class="col-md-8" type="file" />
```

I am getting this at client side by this code:

```
var data = new FormData();
var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files; // for multiple files
data.append("file", files[0]);
```

which is working file and i can even send it to web service as below:

```
var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
```

But i want to send a single value which is `Foler name` along with this formdata which i get from a hidden value.

I have tried below:

```
data.append("folder", $("#hdnFolderName").val());
```

and when i try below in web service it is returning null:

```
var folder = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["folder"];
```

In web service i am not able to retrieve this folder value. can anyone show me correct way?

Comment: It doesn't seem like your value would be in `.files`.
Try `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` and its contents instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was to use below code:

```
var folder = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["folder"];
```

which was suggested first by [Satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal) but then he deleted the answer!